# PHP Smarty Tag in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, smarty

i am working on a shop that uses smarty tag. I want to do following sql query:

```
{php}
    $sql = "SELECT intraship_shipmentnumber FROM orders WHERE orders_id = {$ORDER_NUMBER} ";
{/php}
```

when i insert a static order number the sql query works, but it does not work with the smarty tag and i poorly have no idea how to insert it so it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a solution myself. Here it is for anyone who is interested:

First you assign a variable via Smarty:

```
{assign var=test value=$ORDER_NUMBER}
```

Then you can put this in a PHP Variable which you can use:

```
$order = $this->get_template_vars('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Smarty expert. But could you try:

```
{php}
    $sql = "SELECT intraship_shipmentnumber FROM orders WHERE orders_id = {/php}{$ORDER_NUMBER}{php} ";
{/php}
```